# How to directly call admin in django urls

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-admin, django-urls

In my python I have urls like :

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin_site.urls),
    url(r'^ckeditor/', include('ckeditor_uploader.urls')),
] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

when i have url like : http://localhost:8000/ i am getting screen like

[image]

but when i am using  http://localhost:8000/admin i am able to use my admin login pannel.what i actually want is when i use http://localhost:8000/ it directly call the http://localhost:8000/admin .can anyone please help me related this ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just remove the word admin from your url, like this:

```
path('', admin_site.urls),
```

This means that your admin page will be your home page.

Alternatively, you could do a redirect:

```
from django.views.generic.base import RedirectView
from django.urls import re_path
re_path(r'^$', RedirectView.as_view(url='/admin'))
```

Comment: i tried this befor but because of this i have to change alot like template,static,staticfiles and other routes which is created before so i am here for another poosible way like redirections..

Comment: This is what i exactly want thanks alot to you @MeL